Typo3 Powermail upper limit to data sent via form
I've a simple question about the powermail extension (a bit outdated on my site: 10.4.2 & Typo3 11).
Is it possible setting an upper limit to the filled forms sent that I will receive?
I.E. no more than N subscriptions via that form...
Thanks a lot in advance for the reply,
Fabiano

Took me no more than a couple of seconds of research, to stumble upon https://github.com/jpmschuler/TYPO3-powermail-limits - "EXT:powermail_limits

This extension allows you to set a submission limit for a TYPO3 EXT:powermail form" And the compatibility requirements match your extension & typo versions.

